# EasyPHP - Taking WordPress live to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, easyphp

I have been giving a task for a client to take their existing word press database and make changes to the client specifications. However I do not want to edit this database on their live website so I am trying to pull it from their server and work on it locally.

The problem I am having is that I managed to drag all the files successfully from their host and put them onto my localhost, however when I try to view it locally I get the error: "Error establishing a database connection"

As they can't give me their database to work locally on, I am in the position where I have their files locally on my machine but I am trying to access their live database.

So when I pulled the files down locally, I expected that my local machine will just connect to their live database automatically.

In the wp-config.php file I have the settings:

```
define('DB_NAME', '');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

*Removed the db_name, username and password*

The line I am looking at is 'localhost', would this need to be changed to their host? Because from what this says is that it will check the localhost on my local machine for the database which I do not have.

However on the server it would say check the localhost on the server which would be there?

So to sum this up, to get this working correctly, would I either need:

1. The database to export to my local machine
2. The IP / Hostname of where the database is stored?

Also is it possible to find out what this is without directly contacting the client as I doubt they will know this.

Cheers

Comment: did you try with the IP/hostname of the machine where database is stored?

Comment: I don't have that kind of information, I have to go back to my boss and make a claim to say, we need this otherwise I can't work, I just wanted to double check this before I go making that claim. We don't have access to their web provider also which means I can't find it out myself.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you will either need the access to their database or a copy of their database to work upon.

Comment: I managed to solve it by pinging their live website through the command line

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the IP they were using by pinging the live website through the command line.